Minimized incoming call
During an incoming call my app is sent to background, and the phone screen is displayed fullscreen (Image 1). I'd like to keep the app open and the phone call window minimized at the bottom like in Google Maps while navigating (Image 2). Is there a way?

This seems like a feature of a specific realization of Android OS - try running emulator with pure Android (which is default in Android Studio) and see if the behavior is the same.

@BratyslavMorhunov In emulator the call screen is show in fullscreen. But on that specific device Google Maps show  the call screen minimized and my app show it fullscreen, so I'm wondering if there a specific option to tell the OS to manage the phone screen like a popup or something.

So you can try to google the solution for your specific OS realization (Samsung, Xiaomi, etc.), but this feature may be unreachable for developers. Also keep in mind that even if the solution exists it will work only with this type of OS and may not work with other devices.
